# Styling appended text that includes template literals

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to style a short sentence including a word and a number, created using spans and template literal so we have, for instance, the Review word in red and the template literal in blue, but I can't make the code work:

```js
let slide_launched = 10;
let cardState = document.getElementById("cardState");
cardState.innerHTML = `<span style="color:red" >Review </span><span style="color:blue font-weight:700" >${slide_launched - 1}</span>`;
```

```html
<div class="containerList">
<ul id="list">

 <li>
  <span>Number:</span>
  <span id="cardState"></span>
 </li>
  
</ul>
</div>
```

I have tried to separate the innerHTML appending portions of text and style them individually but that doesn't work too:

```js
 let slide_launched = 10;
 let cardState = document.getElementById("cardState");
 
cardState.innerHTML = `<span style="color:red" >Review </span>`;

cardState.innerHTML += `<span style="color:blue font-weight:700" >${slide_launched - 1}</span>`
```

```html
<div class="containerList">
    <ul id="list">

     <li>
      <span>Number:</span>
      <span id="cardState"></span>
     </li>
      
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you're just missing a semi-colon. Try ` <span style="color:blue; font-weight:700"...`

Comment: You have forgot a `;` then: `cardState.innerHTML += '<span style="color:blue; font-weight:700" >${slide_launched - 1}</span>'` . In most of the time you can find solution by getting inspect element

Comment: Thanks man, you saved me...

Comment: Note that you can (and arguably should) use classes for this purpose. That way you don't need to worry about missing semicolons in HTML in JavaScript. You just need to worry about it in one CSS file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to add semicolon:

```
<span style="color:blue font-weight:700" >${slide_launched - 1}</span>
```

Change to:

```
<span style="color:blue;font-weight:700" >${slide_launched - 1}</span>
```

You need to add semicolon after every `property:value;`